# Dynamic table cells with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table

Something is wrong on this code. I have worked many hours and can not see what is wrong. When I pick a name from the suggestion list, all table cells are having the same name selected. 
What is the trick?

```
<td title="Workers">  

//// The input for the table cell ////

   <input type="text" name="workername" 
id="workername-<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>" 
class="workername-<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>"
placeholder="Enter a Name" value="<?php echo $rs['username'];?>"
   /> 

//// Suggestion list under the input value ////


 <div class="suggestionlist<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>">
 </div>  


//// The script to get input and show the suggestion list under input   ////    

   <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.workername-<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>').keyup(function(){  
   var query = $(this).val();  
        if(query != ''){  
            $.ajax({  
            url:"searchallworkersfromdatabase.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{query:query},  
            success:function(data) { 

           $('.suggestionlist<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>').fadeIn();  
           $('.suggestionlist<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>').html(data);  
        }  
            });  
    }  
 });  
     $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
     $('.workername-<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>').val($(this).text());  
     $('.suggestionlist<?php echo $rs['taskid']; ?>').fadeOut();  
         });  
             }); 
   </script> 
</td>
```

Comment: you forgot to point out your problem

Comment: Well, as I wrote. All table cells are having the same name selected. This is not cool.

Comment: you have to create a fiddle example link with some hard-coded value. so that we can check and rectify and let you know

Comment: I can not fiddle it with a lot of database connections... Check this link. I am trying to do the same autocomplete as on this link. I am trying to apply this on a table cell with many rows.  http://www.webslesson.info/2016/06/ajax-autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-and-mysql.html